# How to show phone storage files like .pdf, .doc, .ppt, .xls etc in web view android

Tags: android

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
String filePath = /storage/sdcard0/someFile.pdf
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
File htmlFile = new File(filePath);
        webView.loadUrl(htmlFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Above code not working showing blank screen

Comment: Why you want to open internal file on webview?

Comment: i am developing a application which is running online and offline the application contains different type of files and don't want to open files out of application that's why i want to open files in web view.